# Does R have inverse fast fourier transform function?

Tags: r

I believe R has ifft function, but whenever I enter `?ifft` it returns this message:

```
No documentation for ‘ifft’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??ifft’
```

What is the package for ifft?

Comment: What prevents you from googling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `signal` library. For further information you may use this resource: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/signal/versions/0.7-6/topics/ifft

Comment: You mean to install the signal packages?

Comment: @rrr Yes. `install.packages("signal")`. Do not forget to link the library by `library("signal")` afterwards.